# Having 1 thread execute multiple methods at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

So I have a list with 900+ entries in C#. For every entry in the list a method has to be executed, though these must go all at the same time. First I thought of doing this:

```
public void InitializeThread()
{
   Thread myThread = new Thread(run());
   myThread.Start();
}

public void run()
{
   foreach(Object o in ObjectList)
   {
      othermethod();
   }
}
```

Now the problem here is that this will execute 1 method at a time for each entry in the list. But I want every single one of them to be running at the same time.

Then I tried making a seperate thread for each entry like this:

```
public void InitializeThread()
{
   foreach(Object o in ObjectList)
   {
      Thread myThread = new Thread(run());
      myThread.Start();
   }
}

public void run()
{
   while(//thread is allowed to run)
   {
      // do stuff
   } 
}
```

But this seems to give me system.outofmemory exceptions (not a suprise since the list has almost a 1000 entries.
Is there a way to succesfully run all those methods at the same time? Either using multiple threads or only one?

What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is this: I have a GMap, and want to have a few markers on it. These markers represent trains. The marker pops up on the GMap at a certain point in time, and dissappears when it reaches it's destination. All the trains move about at the same time on the map.

If I need to post more of the code I tried please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Unless you have something like [Blue Gene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Gene), it's not possible to actually run the methods at the same time. What are the methods doing that you think needs to be run at the same time?

Comment: Every time the methods run it will change a couple of variables, and then place a marker onto a GMap Overlay.

Comment: I don't see anything in that, that would need to be executed all at the same time. On the contrary, are you able to place more than one marker at a time?

Comment: There's no way that can guarantee all your methods will run at the same time. Even if you do over 9000 threads - OS may execute em one by one. Btw `Parallel.ForEach` is the simplest way to go here

Comment: Now that you mention that, I'm pretty sure I can. You would have to individually add each marker to an overlay and then you can add that overlay to the map in 1 go.

Comment: Oh but that means I can have the program changing the variables on after another, and then use a thread to add the overlay to the map everytime, resulting in only using one thread right?

Comment: You need to fix your question so that it makes sense. A computer can literally do only as many things "at the same time" as it has the hardware to support. For executing program statements, the hardware required is a CPU core, so you'll never have more methods executing "at the same time" than you have CPU cores. So either you're asking for the impossible, or you really want something other than what you've literally asked for. Please fix the question so we can understand what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Executes a foreach operation on an IEnumerable in which iterations may
>   run in parallel.

And you use it like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ObjectList, (obj) =>
{
   // Do parallel work here on each object
});
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee all items running at the same time (like the question wanted), though, does it? It will run as many of them concurrently as it can based on the machine executing the code. I'd say this is the right answer, but it's probably worth pointing that out.

Comment: *"running all items at the same time"* is a always a factor of the amount of cores your machine is running. `Parellel.ForEach` will attempt to partition that `IEnumerable` according to the underlying resources available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm going to try this and I'll get back when I get any results.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to run so many threads at the same time. It's usually done by putting all the objects into an array and looping through the array in a circle:

1. Pull the state of an object
2. Calculate where this object should be right now (This is the method that you wish to run on every object, but it can not run from start to end. You will have to update it. It takes the last state of the object, and calculates the current state)
3. Save its state accordingly
4. Refresh the scene from the array
5. move to the next object in the list
6. End of the list? go back to the first object.

Comment: How can you say something is not possible and then, in the same paragraph, say how it can be done?